# Is life about effort and reward marathons?

Tags: psychology

This question is perhaps better suited to the statistics stack exchange. Or, even better, to the psychology stack exchange.

It is about how many people, even across sexes and ages, engage in pleasure marathons.

This, is, experiences, where a person, from, a personal standpoint, undergoes a given amount of effort (which, may be small, or large), only to reward themselves (or, better, get rewarded), with due amount of satisfaction.

When the reward is too far away from the effort, the person, may just collapse.

Is this what life is about?

Comment: Actually this one is indeed a fundamental philosophical question about (1) human nature and (2) the meaning of life. Problem is, there's no consensus on this in philosophy, so this question is likely to garner discussion and opinions, and not answers.

Comment: Please cut back on the excessive use of commas, you are very difficult to understand.